# Socket.on('error') What is this?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I placed this line into my code

socket.on('error', function () { ... })

And I am counting this errors,and I saw too many inputs.What could be causing this ? I can't understand.

Comment: `socket.on` is a listener. You are listening for an incoming socket by the name of `error`. Every time someone emits `error` to your server, the code under `socket.on('error',function(){...});` should run. You should include more code, because I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: error event is emitted from the server when you have enforced authorization on server side and client somehow fails to authorize it to the server

Comment: @MOmayr How can I resolve the fails ?

Comment: can you post your server and client code here?